# Measuring execution time of (custom) allocators?

Tags: c++, memory-management, time

The task is to measure the performance of `new` against a custom allocator: `Stack<size>`. The method I thought it would be adequate is to measure the time it takes to allocate a number of memory blocks of given size. The selected ranges are:

- bytes: 100, 1000,...,1000000
- number of blocks: 20000, 40000,...,200000

To measure `new` and `Stack`, the following code is used:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <cstddef>                  // std::size_t
#include <ctime>                    // std::clock_t

#include "MyStack.h"

#define BLOCK_SIZE 100              // Test_Object size    

struct Measurement
{
   Measurement(std::size_t n, double t): blocks_number(n), cpu_time(t) { }

   std::size_t blocks_number;
   double cpu_time;
};

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
class Test_Object
{
    char data[BLOCK_SIZE];
};

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void sequential_deallocation(std::size_t number)
{
    std::vector<Test_Object*> obj_arr(number + 1);

    // allocate
    for (std::size_t allocations = 0; allocations <= number; ++allocations)
    {
        obj_arr[allocations] = new Test_Object;
    }

    // deallocate in reverse order
    for (std::size_t allocations = number; allocations-- > 0;)
    {
        delete obj_arr[allocations];
    }
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void time_test()
{
    std::vector<Measurement> data; 

    for (std::size_t number = 20000; number <= 200000; number += 20000) // memory block number 
    {
        std::clock_t start = std::clock();

        sequential_deallocation(number);

        // find CPU execution time
        double time = 1000.0 * (std::clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

        data.emplace_back(Measurement(number, time));
    }

    std::string name("OperatorNewSize");     
    name += std::to_string(BLOCK_SIZE) + ".txt";
    write_to_file(name, data); // writes the contents of vector: data to file: name
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main ()
try
{
    // measure new
    time_test(); 

    // measure Stack
    const std::size_t number = 2500;
    const std::size_t bytes = number * sizeof(Test_Object);
    Stack<bytes> s;

    std::vector<Test_Object*> obj_vect(number);

    std::clock_t start = std::clock();
    for (std::size_t allocations = 0; allocations < number; ++allocations)
    {
        obj_vect[allocations] = reinterpret_cast<Test_Object*>(s.get(sizeof(Test_Object)));
    }


    for (std::size_t allocations = number; allocations-- > 0;)
    {
        s.free(); // not sure if right
    }

    double time = 1000.0 * (std::clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    std::cout <<"Block Size: "<< BLOCK_SIZE <<"\tBlock Number: "<< number <<"\tTime: "<< time <<" [ms]\n";
}
catch (std::exception& e)
{
    std::cerr << e.what();
    getchar();
}
```

I don't know if the method I use is right, i.e. is the compiler optimising some part of the code that makes the time measurement invalid. I store the pointers that hold the allocated memory in vectors and I don't know if that is right

My main concerns are:

- is the described method valid?
- how to store the pointers that hold the allocated memory: vector, array?
- is the measuring of `Stack` right?
- <strike>for some reason I can't allocate memory for more than 2500- 2600 `Test_Object`s in `Stack`, why?</strike><sup>Answered by @user4581301 in the comments below.</sup>
- is there a way to automate the iteration over the size of the memory block, here varied by `#define BLOCK_SIZE 100`; or the template parameter specifying the size of the `Stack<size>`?

---

`MyStack.h`

```
#ifndef MyStack_h
#define MyStack_h

template <std::size_t N>                                     
class Stack
{
    typedef unsigned char uchar;
    typedef std::size_t uint;

    uchar* data;                                                
    uchar* end;                                              
    uchar* top;                                              

    uint index;
    uint memory_blocks_sizes[N];            // byte is the smallest memory unit 

    bool is_full() { return !(top < end); }

    bool is_empty() { return top == data && index == 0; }

    void update(uint n, bool allocate) 
    {
        if (allocate)
        {
           top += n;                        // shift top n bytes towards the end        
            memory_blocks_sizes[index] = n; // store size of allocated block
            ++index;                        // update index to store next
        }
        else
        {
            --index;                        // update index to get previous
            n = memory_blocks_sizes[index]; // get size of last allocated block
            top -= n;                       // shift top towards the start(data)
        }
    }

public:
    Stack()
        : data(new uchar[N]), end(data + N), top(data), index(0)
    {

    }

    ~Stack() { delete[] data; }

    void* get(uint n)
    {
        if (is_full() || ((top + n) > end))
        {
            throw std::bad_alloc("Stack::get()::Stack Overflow!\n");
        }
        void* ret = (void*) top;

        update(n, true);

        return ret;
    }

    void free()
    {
        if (is_empty())
        {
            throw std::bad_alloc("Stack::free()::Stack Underflow!\n");
        }
        update(0, false);
    }

    uint available() const { return uint(end - top); };
};


#endif
```

Comment: What you are allocating with `uint memory_blocks_sizes[N]` is at least 2 bytes (and probably 4 or 8 bytes) per N. `sizeof(Test_Object)` is 100. Number is currently 2500, so N = 250000. That is a minimum of 500000 bytes and much more likely 1 or 2 MB. `s `is an Automatic variable, and the typical Automatic storage area is relatively small, 1 to 10 MB. If you want a bigger `Stack`, you will have to dynamically allocate `s`, make `s` static, or convince the OS to allocate you a larger Automatic data store.

Comment: @user4581301 if you convert the comment into an answer, it would be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `std::chrono` from C++11, it's pretty accurate. If your compiler doesn't support it, you can use  `QueryPerformanceCounter` on windows.

Comment: @Ziezi On a side note, if you really want to control allocations, conside implementing custom allocators: https://blog.molecular-matters.com/2012/08/14/memory-allocation-strategies-a-linear-allocator/